# Make action after script appended and loaded completely in JS

Tags: javascript

```
function loadZendeskWidget() {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.type = 'text/javascript'
    script.async = true
    script.src = '//v2.zopim.com/?key'
    document.body.appendChild(script)
}
```

When action onClick occurs, I append my script to HTML and then as I understand the loading of this script happens. Is there any possible way to get information about when this script loaded and attached to the window. In my case logic next :

1. User click on button open chat
2. We append chat in body, then chat loaded and `window.$zopim` the value attached to window object. Then I want to make `window.$zopim.livechat.window.show()`

I've tried :

```
script.onload = function () { window.$zopim.livechat.window.show() }
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK allows an onload callback

```
$zopim(function(){
   // Custom code here
});
```

E.g.

```
$zopim(function(){
  $zopim.livechat.window.show()
});
```